# .htaccess redirect based on random key

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, random

I am trying to do a redirect based on a random key, like this:
`domainnamedotcom/XZI9F01ZmYj4olGAB4Hh`

I would like this to redirect to:

http://domainnamedotcom/application.php?i=XZI9F01ZmYj4olGAB4Hh

This is clearly new territory for me, I thought this would work,
but it isn't...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([0-9]+)$ application.php?i=$1
```

Does anyone know how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your key  is only alphanumeric this will work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ application.php?i=$1
```

The problem with yours was that the [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) wasn't what you needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick Q! That was the problem indeed.
I really need to brush up on my reg expres...